# Crowdsec OpenResty Ubuntu apt upgrade fails

Tags: openresty, crowdsec

While attempting to upgrade the Ubuntu Jammy system I set up for Crowdsec I encountered this (apt upgrade) problem.

nginx is looking for crowdsec_openresty.conf but this file does not exist on my system.

```
Setting up openresty (1.25.3.1-2~jammy1) ...                                               
Job for openresty.service failed because the control process exited with error code.       
See "systemctl status openresty.service" and "journalctl -xeu openresty.service" for details.               
invoke-rc.d: initscript openresty, action "start" failed.
× openresty.service - The OpenResty Application Platform
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openresty.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled
)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-02-16 23:35:02 UTC; 25ms ago
Process: 126310 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on;
master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) CPU: 6ms
Feb 16 23:35:02 crowdsec systemd[1]: Starting The OpenResty Application Platform...
Feb 16 23:35:02 crowdsec nginx[126310]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/crowdsec_openresty.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:20
Feb 16 23:35:02 crowdsec nginx[126310]: nginx: configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
Feb 16 23:35:02 crowdsec systemd[1]: openresty.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 16 23:35:02 crowdsec systemd[1]: openresty.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 16 23:35:02 crowdsec systemd[1]: Failed to start The OpenResty Application Platform.
dpkg: error processing package openresty (--configure):
 installed openresty package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python3-apt (2.4.0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:22.04.19) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openresty-opm:
 openresty-opm depends on openresty (>= 1.25.3.1); however:
  Package openresty is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package openresty-opm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

journalctl -xeu openresty.service

Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]: nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: init_by_lua(conf.d/crowdsec_openresty.conf:5):2>
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no field package.preload['crowdsec']
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/nginx//../lualib/plugins/crowdsec/crowdsec.>
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/crowdsec.ljbc'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/crowdsec/init.ljbc'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/crowdsec.ljbc'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/crowdsec/init.ljbc'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/crowdsec.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/crowdsec/init.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/crowdsec.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/crowdsec/init.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file './crowdsec.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/luajit-2.1/crowdsec.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/crowdsec.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/crowdsec/init.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/crowdsec.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/crowdsec/init.lua'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/crowdsec.so'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/crowdsec.so'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file './crowdsec.so'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/crowdsec.so'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib/lua/5.1/crowdsec.so'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]: stack traceback:
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         [C]: in function 'require'
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec nginx[138239]:         init_by_lua(conf.d/crowdsec_openresty.conf:5):2: in main chunk
Feb 17 02:25:15 crowdsec systemd[1]: openresty.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: `apt install crowdsec-openresty-bouncer`

Comment: Gosh darn it! This fixed it, I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `openresty.service` is failing to start because the file `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/crowdsec_openresty.conf` is missing.

This file is provided by `crowdsec-openresty-bouncer` package, see the [documentation](https://docs.crowdsec.net/u/bouncers/openresty/).

You can install it with `apt install crowdsec-openresty-bouncer`.

Comment: For some reason weeks ago I renamed crowdsec_openresty.conf to crowdsec_openresty.conf.back.

Yesterday I realized this, and renamed the file to crowdsec_openresty.conf and tried to 'apt upgrade' again but apt upgrade choked again. Only when I reinstalled the crowdsec-openresty-bouncer package was I able to start crowdsec again. Thank you very much AlexD

Answer (score 0):

crowdsec_openresty.conf was missing because I weeks ago renamed it crowdsec_openresty.conf.back at some point.
Anyhow, when I re-installed crowdsec-openresty-bouncer today I got crowdsec-openresty-bouncer 1.0.2 whereas I *previously* had version 0.1.10 and now I have no pending updates and Crowdsec can be started.

Answer (score -1):

Install openresty

```
wget -O - https://openresty.org/package/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -   
echo "deb http://openresty.org/package/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > openresty.list
sudo cp openresty.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends openresty
```

Comment: If you check the logs in the question, you can notice that they start with `Setting up openresty (1.25.3.1-2~jammy1)` but fail with `installed openresty package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python3-apt (2.4.0ubuntu3) ...`.